# Creating a module in linux

Tags: c, linux

Im trying to create a module for the linux redhat 2.4.18
as a part of a homework assignment of mine.

and Ive got this part of code at the start of my code:

```
char* filepath;
MODULE_PARAM(filepath,"s");
```

when I compile my code with the makefile ive created im getting:

> intercept.c:22: parse error before string constant intercept.c:22:
>   warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of `MODULE_PARAM'
>   intercept.c:22: warning: data definition has no type or storage class

where line 22 is this line:

```
MODULE_PARAM(filepath,"s");
```

P.S. Ive included: linux\module.h

Comment: Hint: look at `MODULE_PARAM` documentation.

Comment: How is C++ relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo in the macro name:

The right syntax is `MODULE_PARM(filepath, "s");`

Some documentation can be found on http://www.tldp.org : [Passing Command Line Arguments to a Module](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x354.html)l)